# Specflow, not seeing suggested code for Step Definitions

Tags: c#, specflow

After writing a Feature / Scenarios and running a test, I do not see any suggested code for the step definitions in the output like most of the screen casts suggest.

Any ideas on what I'm doing differently?

(edit)I'm using NUnit and Resharper to run the Tests.  I see basic output, but not a neatly defined list like I'm seeing in the screen casts.  Each sample method is listed below the failing step.

Comment: Could you provide some more info:

Which Unit-Test Framework are you using? (NUnit is default)

Are you running the tests from within VisualStudio?

What makes you sure that the test is actually running?

Do you see any output from the running test?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the NUnit GUI test runner, be sure to click on the "Text Output" tab.